# d3 contextmenu not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm just adding bootstrap and jquery to my d3 script.  It's mostly working, but I notice that I'm no longer getting right-click / contextmenu events.  My setup code looks like this:

```
this.svg_canvas = d3.select("#" + this.container_id)
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", this.width)
  .attr("height", this.height)
  .on("click", this._selectNodes.bind(this))
  .on("mousedown", this._handleMouseDown.bind(this))
  .on("contextmenu", function(data, index) { graph_view._showContextMenu(data, index); })
  .call(this.zoom_behavior.bind(this))
;
```

It's worth mentioning that all other gestures -- click, mousedown, and zoom -- appear to be working just fine.

Any ideas of where to look or how to debug this?

Comment: Just a wild guess; is it possible that your `mousedown` code is preventing the default `contextmenu` event from firing?

Comment: Doh.  I was fooled by misplaced debugging statements: `mousedown` and `contextmenu` events are firing just fine.  Faulty css was preventing the context menu from being displayed.  Move along, nothing to see here...

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this isn't really an answer, but since someone upvoted the question, I owe it to them to tell them what I found...

I put debugging statements in my .on('contextmenu') method, as in:

```
var svg_canvas = d3.select('#canvas-id')
  .append('svg')
  ...
  .on('contextmenu', function(d) {
      console.log('>>> contextmenu', d);
      handleContextMenu(d);
  })
  .call(zoomBehavior)
;
```

... and I noticed that it *was* calling my handleContextMenu(), but my menu wasn't appearing.  It took me a while to realize that I'd commented out the HTML that generated the menu, but after that the fix was easy.

What still perplexes me is that d3 did not raise an error on this line:

```
var context_menu = d3.select('#context-menu')
    .on('mouseup', ...)
```

... even though there was no #context-menu id in the DOM.

Comment: You basically wrote - for the element matching the select run the on method. No matches is not an error, just a no-op.